# Can SDL_GetBasePath() and SDL_GetPrefPath() be called before SDL_Init()?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

In my application I would like to use a configuration file. However I have the chicken and egg problem here: the configuration file can even describe how SDL (and other things) should be init'ed. Thus, I would need to call `SDL_GetPrefPath()` before even `SDL_Init()` to get the common place where configuration for my application is stored as per-user basis. I'm not sure if it's possible. I also need `SDL_GetBasePath()` for similar (fall-back) purpose, I know that's ugly but some users would like that optionally for trying to find the configuration file. Reading the configuration file itself is not a problem, as I don't use SDL related functions for that, though I need to get the directory where configuration file can be found.

Surely, I can test if it's work, but it's not the best, it may fail in different SDL versions, on other architecture, or who knows. I would like to know it's safe "by design" (and "future-proof"), or not.

On the SDL-2 wiki, some functions like `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox()` is noted, that it's safe to be used even before `SDL_Init()`, but I am not sure if this is the situation in this case. I'm not sure if SDL-2 wiki is detailed enough to always show the situation like this (as with `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox()`), since this information is not mentioned on the pages of the functions I'm talking about now.

Note, my application is intended to run on Linux, MacOS and Windows, so it would be hard to judge by myself where SDL will put its preference directory after initialization, and also an ugly, redundant stuff then ...

Comment: Not seeing anything too-`SDL_Init()`-dependent in [the source](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f76299105635/src/filesystem) (given that [the Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init) claims the logging system doesn't require initing), might try poking [the mailing list](https://discourse.libsdl.org/c/sdl-development) and possibly adding a documentation clarification request to [the Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/).

Comment: Yes, I also tried to look at the source. I'm also thinking that maybe my solution is flawed. Though I am not sure how to remedy this to be elegant and not depending in the "hope" that it can be done before SDL_Init() which even may change in the future as a non-explained behaviour which should be depended on. Maybe SDL_Init(0); or something like that, and let's init subsystems later, after configuration read? I don't have too much idea currently though, I have the hope that some experienced SDL user may have a good idea here. Or the mailing list, indeed :D

Comment: I think the mailing list is your best bet, this *should* "just" be a documentation problem and I think you have a compelling use-case.

Comment: Ok, bugzilla is a nice idea, I'll do that. Maybe it can even help others in the future with similar question then. Thanks.

Comment: @genpfault thanks for the idea about requesting document clarify in their bugzilla, I did, thus my answer I could compose from their opinion with my ideas mixed below. It seems it's really not a good thing to try without SDL_Init() anyway ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's useful for others too, so this is what I could figure out:

https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3796

I've submitted an SDL bugzilla ticket about this. The answer, that it's basically platform dependent, and not safe for these functions to be used without `SDL_Init()`. May work on some platforms, may not on others (or in the future). However, I got a tip, to use `SDL_Init(0)` and `SDL_Quit()` around the call. So, with my own ideas added as well, something like this:

```
char *my_pref_dir_path = NULL;
if (!SDL_Init(0)) {
    char *p = SDL_GetPrefPath(app_org, app_name);
    if (p) {
        my_pref_dir_path = strdup(p);
        SDL_free(p);
    }
    SQL_Quit();
}
if (!my_pref_dir_path) {
    /* ... panic or exit or whatever ... */
}
```

`SDL_Init(0)` won't initialize too much (not even video or other subsystems, so it won't interfere with the plan that I may not need SDL at all later), but it should be safe now to use the desired functions. After that, `SQL_Quit()` would make SDL "go away". Later, of course, you can have a "proper" SDL initialization, for example: `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)`, just like if this code hasn't been in your program at all before.

Since, I am not sure, if the pointer returned by `SDL_GetPrefPath()` is valid after `SQL_Quit()`, I would `strdup()` it or such, and I use `SDL_free()` before `SQL_Quit()` on the pointer returned by `SDL_GetPrefPath()` since it's recommended by the documentation too anyway. Maybe I'm just too careful here, but I think, it's a safer bet then, if I play tricks like this.

After this code, `my_pref_dir_path` will hold a pointer to the SDL preferences directory string, or NULL, if an error occured.

Comment: Confirming that this solution works as expected on Windows 8 since I see in the Bugzilla report you tested it on Linux.